# what does "camp" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

From a wikipedia article:[1]

> During his career, Mercury's flamboyant stage performances sometimes
>   led journalists to allude to his sexuality. Dave Dickson, reviewing
>   Queen's performance at Wembley Arena in 1984 for Kerrang!, noted
>   Mercury's **"camp" addresses** to the audience and even described him
>   as a "posing, pouting, posturing tart."

I think it may not refer to "camp" as a place (or encampment), but to a gay-related slang that means "a man who behaves in an ostentatiously effeminate way" according to the Google Translator.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury

Comment: "Camp" is an adjective, not a noun; it means "self-consciously artificial or theatrical", and is usually associated with the aesthetic and behavioral styles adopted by some gay cultures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stoney B's definition is right; however, camp is by no means exclusive to the gay community. In its non-gay applications, it's sort of a 1960s word. In today's English you might say "over the top".

Comment: Exactly right about the word being used in other contexts. Although I don't hear _camp_ used like this very often, it seems the adjective form is still in use (as in, "That's a campy TV show").

Comment: Over here in Britain, the word "campy" is not mainstream (and in fact I have never heard it). As far as I'm aware, "camp" is still the usual adjectival form. I don't know why it should need to be supplanted by "campy".